# Dramatic increase startup time

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

1-2 days ago startup time increase from 1-3 second to 10-30 seconds with same code.

I use python 2.7 multithreading.

Code in this request read one value from memcache and return it to user. If memcache empty it read and render simple html-template from template in local filesystem. Both use equal cpu_ms.

Same code work fine in test application. Startup time in test application about 1-2 second.

I send production issue yesterday in night, but don't receive answer.

I try change instance type from F1 to F4, startup time for F4 8-10 seconds.

AppID of my app: f1f2ru

Log record before problem:
[image]

Log record at start problem:
[image]

Log record now:
[image]

Log record in test app:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know reason of first increase startup time.

Problem of increase operations time is my mistake:
my application do query:
    object.date < datetime.datetime.now()

and my datastore have no objects with date < datetime.now(), but it have objects with date = None (null). I forget about null it is normal, indexed value and null < any value.

Answer (score 1):

Without logs etc it's hard to know. But who knows, perhaps Google is running low on resources and your free apps are paying the price.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/instances#Loading_Requests

Currently I get about a 5 second startup time from cold on one of my very simple apps. 30 seconds does seem a long time however.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Warmup_Requests

> App Engine frequently needs to load application code into a fresh instance. This happens when you redeploy the application, when the load pattern has increased beyond the capacity of the current instances, or simply due to maintenance or repairs of the underlying infrastructure or physical hardware.

Or just pay:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/performancesettings?hl=en

> The Idle Instances sliders control the minimum and maximum number of idle instances available to your application at any given time.
>
> The upper slider sets the minimum number of idle instances:
>
> Note: In order to specify the minimum number of idle instances, you must have a paid app.

As usual, the more you pay the better the service.

Comment: I can't attach screenshot (low reputation on stackoverflow). It is paid app. Redeploy don't help for it. It is problem only in one app, test app with same code work fine and have small startup time (test app is free). Now I set minimum idle instance=1, but it is temporary method. Really I haven't high traffic spike and I don't need any idle instance. For google admins: appid of app: f1f2ru

Comment: The problem is that the first request will always hit a "cold" instance unless you have one on standby, and there will always be a time delay before it gets hot. So you might not "need" an idle instance but you "need" one for this really I suppose.

Comment: Before start it problem cold start take about 1 second. Same startup time have my test application with same code and settings.

Comment: So you have two applications, both identical, apart from 1 starts up in 1 second and one takes up to 30 seconds?

Comment: Yes. During experiment (many redeploy, change multithreading type, change instance type) startup time of paid (problem) app is 5-30 seconds (last time it 10 seconds). Startup of test (free, instance type F1) app with same code always 1-1.5 second. Both app deploy from same code.

Comment: I add log screenshots in question.

Answer (score 0):

Are the libraries the same from before or after?  Adding libraries to the source code can and often does increase start up time (AppEngine needs to load them).  It is something easily overlooked, and some of them are really really bloated.

Comment: Yes, all are same. Problem started after 10 days from last deployment. After start problem I try redeploy it and deploy same code to test app. Test app work good. Apps absolute identically.